# I changed the TFS 2010 server computer name

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I Changed the TFS server computer name:

after i changed it i connected to the TFS server from Visual Studio using the new name after changing the connection string for the database (i am using the same server For TFS and TFS database). the connection succeeded, and i retrieved the projects from the Project collection, but when i expand a project i get a RED X on "DOCUMENTS" and "REPORTS" folder.

What do i need to do exactly to make it work. I know i should run a command to change the computer name in the workspaces, but i am not quite sure what is it and how to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

What a bad idea!

Any moderate to complex system has many configuration items, not just one connection string.
To give an idea TFS is composed by: some Web site/services, a Window Service, a SQL instance (DB and Analysis), one or more SQL Server Reporting services, not counting other Windows Services for Build and Test that can be added to the architecture. And both TFS and Sharepoint have a Configuration database.

In [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404883%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) you can get some hints of the steps you should have followed.
Specifically, the "Documents" folder error is about accessing Sharepoint and the "Reports" folder error is a failure of Reporting Services.
Frankly, if it was a simple computer rename, the best course of action is to restore the previous name, and use DNS alias for the new name. This is described in [this post](http://www.edsquared.com/2011/01/03/Using+Friendly+DNS+Names+In+Your+TFS+Environment.aspx).
Another cheap way to fix things is to rebuild a new machine and move the databases from the old server, following [this instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: If you detach your TFS Collection before, could be a good idea. I would remove all installs (TFS, SharePoint and SQL) then install TFS from scratch, avoiding creating the default collection as the last configuration step.
At this point you can attach the TFS Collection and should be fine.

CAVEAT: I cannot see the state of your system, it is based on what I understand from your words. BACKUP everything.